# SQL query rounding down to nearest whole number

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a field in my Access query that is directly pulled from a table in the same database. When I pull the value from my table, the value is rounded down to the nearest whole number. ie 2.999 is rounded down to 2. I don't wish for my field in my query to have any rounding, I want the number directly as is from my table. I tried using the Round([field],4) and that still doesn't work and rounds the field down to the nearest whole number. How do I fix this? My SQL code is below.

```
SELECT  t.Station_ID, t3.[Original_Cut_Height(m)]
FROM [Installs] AS t3 LEFT JOIN ON [Inputting Data] AS t on t.Station_ID = t3.Station_ID;
```

Comment: As per [the ms-access documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/round-function-921ce538-c9a6-41e2-be87-28e685b59935), when not given a second argument *the function rounds to the nearest whole number.*

Comment: @carmelle . . . Nothing in your query is rounding the value.  If you are seeing "2" then either the application where you are viewing the data is converting the value to `2` or the database is storing `2`.

Comment: With the code below it is still rounding down. ```SELECT  t.Station_ID, ROUND(t3.[Original_Cut_Height(m)],4)
FROM [Installs] AS t3 LEFT JOIN ON [Inputting Data] AS t on t.Station_ID = t3.Station_ID```

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay thanks. How can I check if the value is being converted to a 2 or if the database is storing it as a 2? My other fields in my query show the value from the table directly so I'm confused why it's just this field.

Comment: @carmelle . . . I don't think you need to ask.  If you see a `2`, that's probably what is in the database.  You could multiply by 1000 and see if you get anything other than 2000.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried multiplying it and get 3000. When in the original table it is indeed 3.658. Is there a setting that is causing this?

Comment: @carmelle . . . You are probably loading a value into an integer.  I would recommend changing the data type to a `numeric`/`decimal` (*with decimal places*!!!) and re-load the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my Table. In the table the number was based on an IIF statement and although the number was in my table was displaying as a decimal, it was being pulled over as an integer rounded down to the nearest whole number. Putting `CDbl()` around the numbers of the IIF statement in the original table solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
SELECT  t.Station_ID, CDbl (t3.[Original_Cut_Height(m)]) AS Original_Cut
FROM [Installs] AS t3 LEFT JOIN ON [Inputting Data] AS t on t.Station_ID = t3.Station_ID;
```

Comment: This did not quite work and the error I get is "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(t3.[Original_Cut_Height(m)] AS FLOAT)'

Comment: Sorry but this was access sql query then I updated. I think CDec() function also works

Comment: The query ran but it is still showing the value rounded down to the nearest whole number.

Comment: Did u use CDec() function instead? In addition do you have any previous sql query to get the data? This can be a int/int problem there has to be like int/float or float/int or likewise.